# Event in Unity seemingly has no methods subscribed to it

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I have three GUI buttons for certain actions in a game. The player can show Empathy, Pity or Tough Love to a Hostage Taker to manipulate them. What I plan to do is to press the GUI button for Empathy, for example, and have it raise an "OnEmpathy" event. This OnEmpathy event will then notify each HostageTaker class that the player has shown Empathy and they react accordingly. Now, for some code examples.

```
public class HostageTaker {  

public void OnEnable()
{
    ButtonHandler.OnEmpathy += this.EmpathyControl; //This statement here is where EmpathyControl SHOULD subscribe to the OnEmpathy event.
    MonoBehaviour.print("Debug");
}
public void EmpathyControl()
{
    //Game related actions here
}
```

The "OnEnable" event triggers instantly, as soon as the HostageTaker is put into a level, so what I believe would happen is that as soon as any HostageTaker is added to a level, they'll automatically subscribe to the OnEmpathy event with this line: `ButtonHandler.OnEmpathy += this.EmpathyControl;`

Now, the ButtonHandler script:

```
public class ButtonHandler : NegotiationControls {
public delegate void EmpathyCall();
public static event EmpathyCall OnEmpathy;

public void OnMouseDown() 
{
    if (this.name == "Empathy" && OnEmpathy != null) //Button identification & null event check.
    {
        print("Empathy Called.");
        OnEmpathy();
    }
    else if(this.name == "Pity")
    {
        print("Pity Called.");
    }
    else if(this.name == "Tough Love")
    {
        print("Tough Love Called.");
    }
    else
    {
        print("Call error. Cannot identify button or OnEmpathy is Null.");
    }
}
```

Now, at this point, EmpathyControl() should be subscribed to OnEmpathy in the Button Handler script. I plan to implement some actual event parameters so that I won't have to manually identify each button using strings, but for now, it works. Pity and Tough Love seem to trigger their Debug print statements as I would expect, but Empathy doesn't trigger, instead resorting to the else condition.

That means, naturally, that OnEmpathy is null. The only question is, why? I've subscribed the EmpathyControl method to the event in the ButtonHandler script, and I've definitely instantiated a HostageTaker in the TestLevel script that runs as soon as the first level starts. The only problem is that TestLevel's only HostageTaker doesn't seem to subscribe to OnEmpathy properly.

**LevelTest script**:

```
public class LevelTest1 : MonoBehaviour {

public HostageTaker HT1 = new HostageTaker();

void Start () 
{
    HT1.customName = "Debug";
}
```

Comment: How is this question related to Unity?

Comment: I think your question could be a lot shorter, and you could easily remove the extra info about your game. Making a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) goes a long way to getting an answer. (You can also remove the "didn't get any answers anywhere else" and "thanks in advance," those are assumed. :) )

Comment: @YacoubMassad Well, the problem was occurring with a game that I'm making in Unity, so I figured I'd need to let people know that. It's a problem with C#, technically, but I figure that Unity probably has something to do with a the problem.

Comment: @31eee384 I was a little worried that I wasn't giving enough information to begin with. Edited.

Comment: Is HostageTaker a MonoBehaviour?

Comment: @ArmyNoodles No. I was having problems when Unity told me that I couldn't instantiate a new class if that class inherits from Monobehaviour, so now HostageTaker doesn't inherit or derive from any other classes.

Comment: @Grizzly and you are calling OnEnable yourself? Unity does it automatically, but only on Monobehaviour objects. You can instantiate one by calling `AddComponent<YourMonobehaviourType>()` on a GameObject.

Comment: @ArmyNoodles Sorry, but it doesn't seem to have made any difference, although, I did note that when I added the subscribe statement to the `public void Start()` it still didn't call. That's odd. The Start event is called as soon as a script starts running, so if that doesn't call, the script isn't running. I added a debug statement to the Start function, and it really isn't being called, yet, the HostageTaker I instantiated in the LevelTest script is definitely active. I've added the LevelTest script above, although it's not very long and I'm not sure if it'll be of much use.

Answer (score 0):

The condition doesn't have to be false because of OnEmpathy being null, maybe the object name is not "Empathy". When you can rule that out, here's a minimal working state you can start from:

producer component

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EventProducer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event System.Action theEvent;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (theEvent != null && GUILayout.Button("Raise event"))
            theEvent.Invoke();
    }
}
```

consumer component

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EventConsumer : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnEnable()
    {
        EventProducer.theEvent += OnEvent;
    }

    void OnEvent()
    {
        Debug.Log("event received!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I forgot to mention, but the debug statement `print("Empathy Called.");` will still trigger when I remove the `OnEmpathy != null`. The object's name is definitely Empathy, and the same works with both Pity and Tough Love. Everything stops working as soon as the null event check is added, so the problem must be related to that, I believe.